# Wrap text in first cell

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap a text label in the first column of my table into a span. It seems pretty straight-forward, b ut I seem to be missing something. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('#myTable tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    var lbl = $(this).val();
    lbl.wrap('<span class="new" />');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a td and you are wrapping text.. so use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) - val is for inputs

```
$('#myTable tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    var lbl = $(this).contents();
    lbl.wrapAll('<span class="new"></span>');
});
```

Or you can use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) - which does the same thing as above

```
$('#myTable tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).wrapInner('<span class="new"></span>');
});
```

Heck, you don't even have to loop.. just do

```
$('#myTable tr td:first-child').wrapInner('<span class="new"></span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/UcJ49/

Answer (score 0):

```
var lbl = $(this).val();
alrtLbl.wrap('<span class="new" />');
```

supposed to be

```
var lbl = $(this).contents();
lbl.wrap('<span class="new" />');
```